# Let ${\varepsilon=\{A\subseteq\Bbb R:A \text { or } A^C \ \text {is countable}\}}.$ Show that $\varepsilon\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\varepsilon = \{A \subseteq \Bbb R : A \ \text  {or} A^C \ \text {is countable}\}$. I want to show that $\varepsilon \subseteq \mathcal B(\Bbb R).$

As you probably already know $\epsilon$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $\Bbb R$. Here $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$ denotes the Borel-algebra in $\Bbb R.$

I've already proved that $\epsilon$ is not finitely generated. Now I'm asked to show that $\epsilon \subseteq \mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ and say a few words about $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ being finitely generated (I've proven this) vs. $\epsilon$ being not (Is there anything special or important about this ?)

I see that if $A \in \epsilon$ we have $A$ or $A^C$ being countable, but why must $A$ then belong to $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: Because each singletons is closed, hence Borel. Thus, every countable set is Borel (why?).

Comment: Ahh i see, how about Borel is finitely generated while $\epsilon$ is not ? What is special / to be said about this ?

Comment: I don't know what a "finitely generated $\sigma$-Algebra" is. My only interpretation would be that this means $\mathcal{B} = \sigma(M)$ for some finite set $M \subset \mathcal{B}$. But I am pretty sure that this is false.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is finitely generated just means there exist a counably set $D$ of subsets of $X$ such that $\epsilon = \sigma(D)$. Here $\sigma(D)$ means the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $D$ :).

Comment: @user111854: It's countable, not countably (or it could be countably infinite, but I doubt that's what you mean). In any case, it doesn't make sense to call the property you mention finitely generated, it's countably generated!

Comment: Sorry, guys, I removed the first "tiny", but removing the second did something wrong. Can somebody with enough reputation solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The interesting thing about that fact is, that although $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ is "bigger" than $\epsilon$ (i.e. it contains more sets), it needs less subsets to generate it. Maybe you think about it, why this can be, and probably even makes sense!

For the "$\subset$"-relation note that it suffices to show that a countable set lies in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. But this is true, since a countable set is a countable union of one-point-sets, but those are in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: yes or terminal object in SET.

Comment: as i said this is correct.

Comment: I edited the post now.

Comment: I've been thinking. Can you give an argument why it makes sense ? Is it because $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ has the property of containing all singletons ?